# Problema de lógica con discord.py y la base de datos

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

recientemente he estado cacharreando haciendo un bot de discord con python, tengo la mayoría de funciones funcionando correctamente, pero hay una en cuestión ($forzarsalida) que no logro averiguar como arreglar, la función en concreto lo que debería hacer es que ejecutando el comando tageando a un usuario agarraría su ID la comprobaría en la bd y debería colocar en la columna start_time como Null para detener el fichaje y añadir el tiempo contado a la columna total_time de la bd, el problema es que no logro hacer que cambie la columna a Null y cierre el fichaje del usuario forzosamente.

Dejo el código completo a continuación.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import aiomysql
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from discord.ext.commands import DefaultHelpCommand
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random
from discord import Game
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from discord import Activity, ActivityType
from discord.ext import tasks

# Definir los intents que necesitas
intents = discord.Intents.all()

# Configurar el prefijo que activará los comandos de tu bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)


db_config = {
    'host': 'xxx',
    'port': 3306,
    'user': 'xxx',
    'password': '',
    'db': 'xxx',
}



# Función para verificar roles
def check_roles(ctx):
    usuarios_autorizados = [xxx, xxx]
    return ctx.author.id in usuarios_autorizados

# Función para formatear el tiempo en horas, minutos y segundos
def format_time(seconds):
    td = timedelta(seconds=seconds)
    days, seconds = td.days, td.seconds
    hours, remainder = divmod(seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return f'{days} días, {hours} horas, {minutes} minutos, {seconds} segundos'

# Función para crear el mensaje de éxito al resetear fichajes
def create_reset_success_embed():
    return discord.Embed(
        title='Todos los fichajes han sido borrados.',
        color=discord.Color.red()
    )

# Función para crear el mensaje de error al resetear fichajes
def create_reset_error_embed(error_message):
    return discord.Embed(
        title=f'Error al intentar borrar los fichajes: {error_message}',
        color=discord.Color.red()
    )

# Función para crear el embed al comenzar a fichar
def create_fichar_embed(author_name):
    return discord.Embed(
        title=f'{author_name}, has comenzado a fichar.',
        color=discord.Color.green()
    )

# Función para crear el embed al detener el fichaje
def create_salir_embed(author_name, formatted_time):
  return discord.Embed(title=f'{author_name}, has dejado de fichar.',
                       description=f'Tiempo en esta sesión: {formatted_time}',
                       color=discord.Color.orange())


async def create_table():
    async with aiomysql.connect(**db_config) as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute("""
                SELECT 1 FROM fichajes LIMIT 1
            """)
            table_exists = bool(await cur.fetchone())

            if not table_exists:
                await cur.execute("""
                    CREATE TABLE fichajes (
                        user_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
                        start_time DATETIME,
                        total_time FLOAT
                    )
                """)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Conectado como {bot.user.name}')
    await create_table()
    my_background_task.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)
async def my_background_task():
    """Will loop every 60 seconds and change the bots presence"""
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='xxxx RP | Unete Ya!'))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Fichajes y espiando roles"))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Creado por xxx"))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="xxx el mejor mecanico siuuu"))

# Personalizar la clase HelpCommand
class CustomHelpCommand(DefaultHelpCommand):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Comandos disponibles", color=discord.Color.blue())

        for cog, commands in mapping.items():
            if cog is None:
                # Comandos sin categoría
                filtered = await self.filter_commands(commands, sort=True)
                command_signatures = [self.get_command_signature(c) for c in filtered]
                if command_signatures:
                    cog_name = "General"
                    embed.add_field(name=cog_name, value="\n".join(command_signatures), inline=False)

        # Enviar la lista de comandos al canal
        await self.get_destination().send(embed=embed)

# Asignar la clase personalizada al bot
bot.help_command = CustomHelpCommand()

# Manejar errores de comandos
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Comando no encontrado. ¡Ese comando no existe!")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Faltan argumentos. Asegúrate de proporcionar todos los argumentos necesarios.")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("No tienes permisos para ejecutar este comando.")
    else:
        print(f"Error no manejado: {error}")

# Función para listar a los usuarios que están fichando en este momento
async def listar_fichando(ctx):
    async with aiomysql.connect(**db_config) as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute("SELECT user_id, start_time FROM fichajes WHERE start_time IS NOT NULL")
            results = await cur.fetchall()

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Usuarios fichando en este momento", color=discord.Color.green())
    if not results:
        embed.description = "Nadie está fichando en este momento."
    else:
        for user_id, start_time in results:
            member = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)
            elapsed_time = (datetime.utcnow() - start_time).total_seconds()
            formatted_time = format_time(elapsed_time)
            embed.add_field(name=member.name, value=f'Tiempo fichado: {formatted_time}', inline=False)

    return embed



# Comando para comenzar a fichar
@bot.command(name='fichar', help='Comienza a fichar tiempo')
async def fichar(ctx):
    async with aiomysql.connect(**db_config) as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute("""
                SELECT start_time FROM fichajes WHERE user_id = %s
            """, (ctx.author.id,))
            result = await cur.fetchone()

            if result and result[0]:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f'{ctx.author.name}, ya estás fichando. Utiliza `$salir` para dejar de fichar.',
                    color=discord.Color.orange()
                )
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                await cur.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO fichajes (user_id, start_time, total_time)
                    VALUES (%s, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 0)
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE start_time = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
                """, (ctx.author.id,))
                await conn.commit()

                embed = create_fichar_embed(ctx.author.name)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

# Comando para detener el fichaje
@bot.command(name='salir', help='Detiene el fichaje')
async def salir(ctx):
  async with aiomysql.connect(**db_config) as conn:
    async with conn.cursor() as cur:
      await cur.execute(
          """
                SELECT start_time, total_time FROM fichajes WHERE user_id = %s
            """, (ctx.author.id, ))
      result = await cur.fetchone()

      if result and result[0]:
        start_time, total_time = result
        elapsed_time = (datetime.utcnow() - start_time).total_seconds()
        await cur.execute(
            """
                    UPDATE fichajes SET total_time = total_time + %s, start_time = NULL WHERE user_id = %s
                """, (elapsed_time, ctx.author.id))
        await conn.commit()
        formatted_time = format_time(elapsed_time)

        # Pasar formatted_time como argumento a create_salir_embed
        embed = create_salir_embed(ctx.author.name, formatted_time)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f'{ctx.author.name}, no estás fichando actualmente.',
            color=discord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


# ... Resto del código ...



# Comando para añadir o restar tiempo a un usuario
@bot.command(name='añadirt',
             help='Añade o resta tiempo a un usuario')
async def añadirtiempo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, time: int = 0):
    if member is not None:
        # Lista de IDs de usuarios autorizados
        usuarios_autorizados = [xxx, xxx]

        # Verificar si el ID del usuario que ejecutó el comando está en la lista de usuarios autorizados
        if ctx.author.id in usuarios_autorizados:
            async with aiomysql.connect(**db_config) as conn:
                async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                    try:
                        # Actualizar el tiempo de fichaje
                        await cur.execute(
                            """
                            UPDATE fichajes SET total_time = total_time + %s
                            WHERE user_id = %s
                            """, (time * 60, member.id))
                        await conn.commit()

                        await ctx.send(f'Se ha añadido {time} minutos a {member.name}.')
                    except Exception as e:
                        await ctx.send(f'Error al añadir tiempo: {e}')
        else:
            await ctx.send('No tienes permisos para este comando.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Debes mencionar al usuario al que deseas añadir o restar tiempo.')

# Comando para ver el tiempo fichado o la lista completa de fichajes
@bot.command(name='data',
             help='Muestra el tiempo fichado o la lista completa de fichajes')
async def data(ctx, *, argumento=None):
    if argumento == 'all':
        async with aiomysql.connect(**db_config) as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute("""
                            SELECT user_id, total_time FROM fichajes ORDER BY total_time DESC
                        """)
                results = await cur.fetchall()

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Lista de fichajes",
                              color=discord.Color.blue())
        for user_id, total_time in results:
            member = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)
            formatted_time = format_time(total_time)
            embed.add_field(name=member.name,
                            value=f'Tiempo fichado: {formatted_time}',
                            inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        member = ctx.author
        async with aiomysql.connect(**db_config) as conn:
            async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                await cur.execute(
                    """
                            SELECT total_time FROM fichajes WHERE user_id = %s
                        """, (member.id,))
                result = await cur.fetchone()

                if result:
                    total_time = result[0]
                    formatted_time = format_time(total_time)

                    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Tiempo fichado de {member.name}',
                                          color=discord.Color.blue())
                    embed.add_field(name="Tiempo fichado",
                                    value=formatted_time,
                                    inline=False)

                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                else:
                    await ctx.send(f'{member.name} no ha fichado.')

# ... Resto del código ...



# Comando para forzar la salida de fichaje de un usuario
@bot.command(name='forzarsalida', help='Fuerza la salida de fichaje de un usuario')
async def forzarsalida(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if check_roles(ctx):
        if member is not None:
            async with aiomysql.connect(**db_config) as conn:
                async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                    try:
                        await cur.execute("SELECT start_time FROM fichajes WHERE user_id = %s AND start_time IS NOT NULL", (member.id,))
                        result = await cur.fetchone()

                        if result:
                            start_time = result[0]
                            elapsed_time = (datetime.utcnow() - start_time).total_seconds()

                            await cur.execute("UPDATE fichajes SET total_time = total_time + %s, start_time = NULL WHERE user_id = %s AND start_time = %s", (elapsed_time, member.id, start_time))
                            print(f"Query: {cur._last_executed}")
                            print(f"Rowcount: {cur.rowcount}")

                            await ctx.send(f'Se ha forzado la salida de fichaje de {member.name}.')
                        else:
                            await ctx.send(f'{member.name} no estaba fichando en ese momento.')
                    except Exception as e:
                        await ctx.send(f'Error al ejecutar la consulta: {e}')
        else:
            await ctx.send('Debes mencionar al usuario al que deseas forzar la salida de fichaje.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('No tienes permisos para este comando.')


# Comando para borrar todos los fichajes
@bot.command(name='reset', help='Borra todos los fichajes')
async def reset(ctx):
    try:
        if check_roles(ctx):
            print("Antes de la ejecución de la consulta de eliminación")
            async with aiomysql.connect(**db_config) as conn:
                async with conn.cursor() as cur:
                    await cur.execute("""
                        DELETE FROM fichajes
                    """)
                print("Después de la ejecución de la consulta de eliminación")
                await conn.commit()
            print("Después del commit")
            await ctx.send('Todos los fichajes han sido borrados.')
        else:
            await ctx.send('No tienes permisos para este comando.')
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f'Error al intentar borrar los fichajes: {e}')


# Comando para listar a los usuarios que están fichando en este momento
@bot.command(name='fichando',
             help='Lista a los usuarios que están fichando en este momento')
async def listar_fichando_command(ctx):
  embed = await listar_fichando(ctx)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

# Token de tu bot (reemplázalo con tu propio token)
token = 'xxxxx'

# Inicia el bot con el token proporcionado
bot.run(token)
```

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida, muchas gracias!